# append columns and count frequency in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
Name       Value1    Value2     Value3
sample1     ttn      mth        lik
sample2     bae      ttn.1      apk
sample3     pas      kasd       mth


dat <- structure(list(Name = c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3"), Value1 = c("ttn", 
"bae", "pas"), Value2 = c("mth", "ttn.1", "kasd"), Value3 = c("lik", 
"apk", "mth")), .Names = c("Name", "Value1", "Value2", "Value3"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to rearrange and count frequency so it would look like:

```
  Value     Source1     Source2
  ttn       sample1
  mth       sample1     sample3
  lik       sample1
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I suggest you provide some example data to play with.

Comment: like the data frame I just added in?

Comment: @pepsimax, that doesn't match the data frame in your example.

Comment: I've replaced it by the dput version of the data so it should be easier for people to import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you will have a ragged array here, so how  about this:

```
sapply(unique(unlist(dat[-1])), function(x) dat[apply(dat[-1],1,function(y) x%in%y),1])
$ttn
[1] "sample1"

$bae
[1] "sample2"

$pas
[1] "sample3"

$mth
[1] "sample1" "sample3"

$ttn.1
[1] "sample2"

$kasd
[1] "sample3"

$lik
[1] "sample1"

$apk
[1] "sample2"
```

Comment: how exactly does this work? Where do I edit your code to choose the column names?

Comment: The `dat[-1]` part selects all but the first column, but you could easily just use `dat[c("Value1","Value3")]`

Comment: When I run it with dat[-1], I dont get the value names like you do. i.e., instead of $ttn [1] "sample1" , I'm just getting [[1]] sample1  . All I changed was "dat" to the name of my real data frame.

Comment: If you use `lapply` rather than `sapply` it will do this. The names are the same as `unique(unlist(dat[-1]))` so you can use this with `names` to add them back.

Comment: Nice. I suspect this would be faster than using `reshape()` and `aggregate()` as I've done.

Comment: I have the names fine though. Its the value that is not appearing correctly. It doesnt tell me $ttn, it just says [1].

Comment: Is there any way you could help me fix this last problem? I'm so close to having it working now thanks to you guys!

Comment: @pepsimax Does using the example and answer as presented work? If it does, then check everything is in the same format. If not, then you need to provide more information to facilitate diagnosis.

Comment: Right, so I got that work, but now the sapply step gives back Error in as.matrix.data.frame(X) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent   . I dont see why dimnames would be incorrect considering I used the correct dimensions

Answer (score 1):

These solutions don't get you *exactly* where you want to be, but might be close enough for you to work from there.

First, some data:

```
temp <- structure(list(Name = c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3"), 
                       Value1 = c("ttn", "bae", "pas"), 
                       Value2 = c("mth", "ttn.1", "kasd"), 
                       Value3 = c("lik", "apk", "mth")), 
                  .Names = c("Name", "Value1", "Value2", "Value3"), 
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
temp
#      Name Value1 Value2 Value3
# 1 sample1    ttn    mth    lik
# 2 sample2    bae  ttn.1    apk
# 3 sample3    pas   kasd    mth
```

These data are in "wide" form. Use `reshape()` to get it into "long" form.

```
temp1 <- reshape(temp, direction = "long", 
                 idvar="Name", varying = 2:4, sep = "")
#              Name time Value
# sample1.1 sample1    1   ttn
# sample2.1 sample2    1   bae
# sample3.1 sample3    1   pas
# sample1.2 sample1    2   mth
# sample2.2 sample2    2 ttn.1
# sample3.2 sample3    2  kasd
# sample1.3 sample1    3   lik
# sample2.3 sample2    3   apk
# sample3.3 sample3    3   mth
```

Now, use `aggregate()` from base R or `dcast()` from the "reshape2" package to aggregate based on the "value" values.

```
aggregate(Name ~ Value, temp1, c)
#   Value             Name
# 1   apk          sample2
# 2   bae          sample2
# 3  kasd          sample3
# 4   lik          sample1
# 5   mth sample1, sample3
# 6   pas          sample3
# 7   ttn          sample1
# 8 ttn.1          sample2
require(reshape2)
dcast(temp1, Value ~ Name, value.var = "Value")
#   Value sample1 sample2 sample3
# 1   apk    <NA>     apk    <NA>
# 2   bae    <NA>     bae    <NA>
# 3  kasd    <NA>    <NA>    kasd
# 4   lik     lik    <NA>    <NA>
# 5   mth     mth    <NA>     mth
# 6   pas    <NA>    <NA>     pas
# 7   ttn     ttn    <NA>    <NA>
# 8 ttn.1    <NA>   ttn.1    <NA>
```

You also mentioned that you would like to "count frequency", in which case, `table()` might also be appropriate:

```
table(temp1$Value, temp1$Name)
# 
#       sample1 sample2 sample3
# apk         0       1       0
# bae         0       1       0
# kasd        0       0       1
# lik         1       0       0
# mth         1       0       1
# pas         0       0       1
# ttn         1       0       0
# ttn.1       0       1       0
```